# How can a gRPC server make calls to REST endpoints

Tags: rest, http, go, server, grpc

I'm currently new to gRPC technology and have been reading up on it.

My current understanding is that `gRPC` is just another protocol just like how `REST` is one. Now lets say I spin up a gRPC server that I want clients to consume, but in that gRPC server I'd like to be able to get information from outside consumer RESTful Apis, (for example https://developer.riotgames.com/api-methods/) is that still possible?

Comment: "is that still possible?" Of course, why wouldn't it?

Comment: i'm not super familiar with like server-side stuff so I was thinking that if it was a gRPC server, it wouldn't be able to make http calls to outside endpoints like (GET, POST)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can make calls to other APIs and services from your own gRPC service code.

Just let your client make a call to your gRPC service. Then, your service makes a REST call to external API (possibly using arguments from client request to your gRPC service) and processes it. Return the result to your client however your gRPC service responds.

Comment: so the gateway on the answer below is only necessary if I want to allow a client to make a REST request to a gRPC server

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use `grcp-gateway` to generate proxy full code available on [go-grpc-tutorial](https://github.com/phuongdo/go-grpc-tutorial) thanks to `phuongdo`[image]

1. install deps:

   ```
   $sudo apt install libprotobuf-dev

   go get google.golang.org/grpc

   go get -u github.com/golang/protobuf/{proto,protoc-gen-go}

   go get -u github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/protoc-gen-grpc-gateway
   ```
2. define service, pb/service.proto:

   ```
   syntax = "proto3";

   option go_package = "echo";

   package echo;

   import "google/api/annotations.proto";

     //Message represents a simple message sent to the Echo service.

    message Message {

    string id = 1;

   string msg = 2;
   }


    //Echo service responds to incoming echo requests.

   service EchoService {

     //Echo method receives a simple message and returns it.

      //The message posted as the id parameter will also be returned.

   rpc Echo(Message) returns (Message) {

   option (google.api.http) = {

       post: "/v1/example/echo/{id}/{msg}"
   };
   }
   }
   ```
3. generate stub for server and clinet

   ```
   $ protoc -I/usr/local/include -I. \
   -I$GOPATH/src \
   -I$GOPATH/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-
    gateway/third_party/googleapis \
    --go_out=google/api/annotations.proto=github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-
    gateway/third_party/googleapis/google/api,plugins=grpc:. \
    pb/service.proto
   ```
4. and `reverse proxy` for `REST API`

   ```
   $ protoc -I/usr/local/include -I. \
   -I$GOPATH/src \
   -I$GOPATH/src/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-
    gateway/third_party/googleapis \
   --grpc-gateway_out=logtostderr=true:. \
   pb/service.proto
   ```
5. server/server.go:

   ```
   package main

   import (
   "flag"

   "github.com/golang/glog"
   pb "github.com/go-grpc-tutorial/pb"
   "golang.org/x/net/context"
   "google.golang.org/grpc"
   "net"
   )

   // Implements of EchoServiceServer

   type echoServer struct{}

   func newEchoServer() pb.EchoServiceServer {
   return new(echoServer)
   }

   func (s *echoServer) Echo(ctx context.Context, msg *pb.Message) 
    (*pb.Message, error) {
   glog.Info(msg)
   return msg, nil
   }

   func Run() error {
   listen, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":50051")
   if err != nil {
       return err
   }
   server := grpc.NewServer()
   pb.RegisterEchoServiceServer(server, newEchoServer())
   server.Serve(listen)
   return nil
   }

   func main() {
   flag.Parse()
   defer glog.Flush()

   if err := Run(); err != nil {
       glog.Fatal(err)
   }
   }
   ```
6. write rest api, server/server-rproxy.go:

   ```
   package main

    import (
   "flag"
   "net/http"
   "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/runtime"
   "github.com/golang/glog"
   pb "github.com/go-grpc-tutorial/pb"
   "golang.org/x/net/context"
   "google.golang.org/grpc"
    )

    var (
   echoEndpoint = flag.String("echo_endpoint", "localhost:50051", 
   "endpoint of EchoService")
    )

   func RunEndPoint(address string, opts ...runtime.ServeMuxOption) 
    error {
   ctx := context.Background()
   ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
   defer cancel()

   mux := runtime.NewServeMux(opts...)
   dialOpts := []grpc.DialOption{grpc.WithInsecure()}
   err := pb.RegisterEchoServiceHandlerFromEndpoint(ctx, mux, *echoEndpoint, dialOpts)
   if err != nil {
       return err
   }

   http.ListenAndServe(address, mux)
   return nil
    }

   func main() {
   flag.Parse()
   defer glog.Flush()

   if err := RunEndPoint(":8080"); err != nil {
       glog.Fatal(err)
   }
    }
   ```
7. build client server/client.go:

   ```
    package main

   import (
   "log"
   "os"

   "golang.org/x/net/context"
   "google.golang.org/grpc"
   pb "github.com/go-grpc-tutorial/pb"
   )

    const (
   address = "localhost:50051"
    defaultName = "PhuongDV"
   )

   func main() {
   // Set up a connection to the server.
   conn, err := grpc.Dial(address, grpc.WithInsecure())
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
   }
   defer conn.Close()
   c := pb.NewEchoServiceClient(conn)

   // Contact the server and print out its response.
   name := defaultName
   if len(os.Args) > 1 {
       name = os.Args[1]
   }
   r, err := c.Echo(context.Background(), &pb.Message{Id: "1", Msg: name})
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatalf("could not greet: %v", err)
   }
   log.Printf("Greeting: %s", r.Msg)
   }
   ```
8. finally run server, client, rest and call rest:

   ```
   $ go run server/server.go

   $ go run client/client.go


   $go run server/server-rproxy.go

    $ curl -X POST "http://localhost:8080/v1/example/echo/1/PhuongDV"
   ```

   [1](https://github.com/phuongdo/go-grpc-tutorial): https://github.com/phuongdo/go-grpc-tutorial
     [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ5ov.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4s7s.png

Comment: this is only for if a user requests a rest call to my gRPC server is it not?

Comment: you can do any design with that as you have all building blocks here,  re your question yes it is: use your client to call gRCP server from REST